# apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

I am trying to do bulk upload in Hbase.I am reading text file and creating Hfile out of that and then loading that Hfile to Hbase.All this is done using my map-reduce job.
I am able to create Hfile and i can see my output directory with /_SUCCESS also that contains data .
But data is not able to load in the Hbase and getting below exception .

```
hadoop.io.MultipleIOException): org.apache.hadoop.io.MultipleIOException: 2 exceptions [org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hbase, access=EXECUTE, inode="/user/m6034690":m6034690:supergroup:drwx------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable secure bulk load, I have just added the following properties to hbase-site.xml.

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.bulkload.staging.dir</name>
  <value>/tmp/hbase-staging</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenProvider,
  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.AccessController,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.SecureBulkLoadEndpoint</value>
</property>
```

And added location for my output directory to  tmp/hbase-staging that that is world-traversable